# How to import xml file data into a csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm importing below xml file data into csv file.

```xml
<State>
<Resident Id="100">
<Name>Sample Name</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Street Line1</StreetLine1>
        <City>City Name</City>
        <StateCode>AE</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
<Resident Id="101">
    <Name>Sample Name1</Name>
    <PhoneNumber>1234567891</PhoneNumber>
    <EmailAddress>sample_name1@example.com</EmailAddress>
    <Address>
        <StreetLine1>Current Address</StreetLine1>
        <City>Los Angeles</City>
        <StateCode>CA</StateCode>
        <PostalCode>56666</PostalCode>
    </Address>
</Resident>
.
.
.
.
</State>
```

Tried code below to import data into csv:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as  ET
tree = ET.parse("C:/Users/Public/Documents/sam.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
with open('C:/Users/Public/Documents/outp.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames=['Id', 'Name', 'PhoneNumber','EmailAddress','StreetLine1','City',
                'StateCode','PostalCode']
    w= csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(e.attrib for e in root.findall('.//file'))
```

I'm running above code in Jupyter(Anaconda) notebook using Python 3.

No data copied into csv files. Only column/field names are populated into csv file.

Kindly let me know why data not populating into csv.
(When I open xml file in excel, data is correct.)

Expected Output is

```
Id  Name    PhoneNumber EmailAddress    StreetLine1 City    StateCode   PostalCode
100 Sample Name 1234567891  sample_name@example.com Street Line1    City Name   AE  12345
101 Sample Name1    1234567891  sample_name1@example.com    Current Address Los Angeles CA  56666
```

Comment: did you try `w.writerows(e.attrib.text for e in root.findall('.//file'))`

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!

I do a LOT of this kind of file work with XML and CSV.  Getting CSV to XML is not terrible, but what you are after will require you to make your own data structure.  The sample XML you gave us is from this site:

http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-xml-to-csv-using-python/

These guys actually solved this for you!  Scroll down on the page after the sample XML you pasted in above, and you will find the python code!

Good luck in your file conversion futures!

`Ethan J.`